# Problem handling regular expression with the table

Tags: regex, bitbucket-pipelines

I have already extracted output from bitbucket pipeline to the .txt file. Now I want to get some of the text (tables at bottom of the code ) with regular expression. Is it possible to extract the table below from the file with grep? If yes, how? I am having issue with writing regex.
Please note that I need to get it from the .txt file

```
12:42:06 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.16.23
12:42:06 INFO: Starting with configs: ['/root/.bzt-rc', 'demo.yml']
12:42:06 INFO: Configuring...
12:42:06 INFO: Proxy settings not set
12:42:06 INFO: Artifacts dir: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/artifacts
12:42:06 INFO: Preparing...
12:42:08 INFO: 1 obsolete CookieManagers are found and fixed
12:42:08 WARNING: Had to add 2 more threads to maintain thread group proportion
12:42:11 INFO: Sending of engine metrics to happysocks is disabled. modules.blazemeter.happysocks-address setting was not provided
12:42:11 INFO: Starting...
12:42:11 INFO: Waiting for results...
12:42:11 INFO: Initiating data feeding...
12:42:11 INFO: Started data feeding: https://a.blazemeter.com/app/#/masters/683912
12:42:11 WARNING: Can't open link in browser: could not locate runnable browser
12:42:12 INFO: Public report link: https://a.blazemeter.com/app/?public-token=LmanlZCRlkowQLGs4T0V64lgxpQKdklzSLLuQ#/masters/683912/summary
12:42:12 WARNING: Failed to check for updates, server returned 5xx.
12:42:19 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  0 fail  0.679 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.679 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:20 INFO: Current: 1 vu    3 succ  0 fail  0.094 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.241 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:21 INFO: Current: 1 vu    7 succ  0 fail  0.208 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.220 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:22 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  0 fail  0.466 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.240 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:23 INFO: Current: 1 vu    3 succ  0 fail  0.502 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.293 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:24 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.442 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.310 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:25 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.559 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.336 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:26 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.452 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.347 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:28 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.495 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.369 avg rt, 0% failures
12:42:30 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  1 fail  0.885 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.414 avg rt, 3% failures
12:42:31 INFO: Changed data analysis delay to 3s
12:42:33 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  0 fail  1.040 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.435 avg rt, 3% failures
12:42:34 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  0 fail  1.453 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.468 avg rt, 3% failures
12:42:35 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  0 fail  0.362 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.464 avg rt, 3% failures
12:42:36 INFO: Current: 1 vu    3 succ  0 fail  0.477 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.465 avg rt, 2% failures
12:42:37 INFO: Changed data analysis delay to 2s
12:42:37 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.479 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.466 avg rt, 2% failures
12:42:38 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.450 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.465 avg rt, 2% failures
12:42:39 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.424 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.463 avg rt, 2% failures
12:42:40 INFO: Current: 1 vu    3 succ  0 fail  0.392 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.458 avg rt, 2% failures
12:42:41 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.423 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.457 avg rt, 2% failures
12:42:42 INFO: Current: 1 vu    2 succ  0 fail  0.906 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.474 avg rt, 1% failures
12:42:43 INFO: Current: 1 vu    1 succ  0 fail  0.186 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.469 avg rt, 1% failures
12:42:44 INFO: Current: 1 vu    5 succ  0 fail  0.206 avg rt    /   Cumulative: 0.446 avg rt, 1% failures
12:42:45 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
12:42:45 INFO: Shutting down...
12:42:45 INFO: Post-processing...
12:42:45 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:34
12:42:45 INFO: Samples count: 80, 1.25% failures
12:42:45 INFO: Average times: total 0.363, latency 0.332, connect 0.012
12:42:45 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |         0.092 |
|          50.0 |         0.313 |
|          90.0 |         0.665 |
|          95.0 |           0.9 |
|          99.0 |         1.453 |
|          99.9 |         1.453 |
|         100.0 |         1.453 |
+---------------+---------------+
12:42:45 INFO: Request label stats:
+-----------------+--------+---------+--------+-------------------------------+
| label           | status |    succ | avg_rt | error                         |
+-----------------+--------+---------+--------+-------------------------------+
| Category List   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.379 |                               |
| Create Favorite |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.222 |                               |
| Delete Folder   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.387 |                               |
| Favorite List   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.260 |                               |
| InsertFolder    |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.747 |                               |
| OAuth           |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.152 |                               |
| Update Favorite |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.137 |                               |
| Update Folder   |  FAIL  |  90.00% |  0.621 | The operation lasted too long |
+-----------------+--------+---------+--------+-------------------------------+
12:42:45 INFO: Sending remaining KPI data to server...
12:42:46 INFO: Uploading all artifacts as artifacts.zip ...
12:42:47 INFO: Uploading /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/artifacts/bzt.log
12:42:48 INFO: Ending data feeding...
12:42:49 INFO: Online report link: https://a.blazemeter.com/app/#/masters/683912
12:42:49 INFO: Artifacts dir: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/artifacts
12:42:49 INFO: Done performing with code: 0
```

Comment: Please share the text as actual text (in a code block), not in an image. Otherwise people can not help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every other line is prefixed, you could use the *-v* option, *"select non-matching lines"*.

```
grep -Pv '^.+?(?:INFO|WARN)' text.txt
```

Output

```
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |         0.092 |
|          50.0 |         0.313 |
|          90.0 |         0.665 |
|          95.0 |           0.9 |
|          99.0 |         1.453 |
|          99.9 |         1.453 |
|         100.0 |         1.453 |
+---------------+---------------+
+-----------------+--------+---------+--------+-------------------------------+
| label           | status |    succ | avg_rt | error                         |
+-----------------+--------+---------+--------+-------------------------------+
| Category List   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.379 |                               |
| Create Favorite |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.222 |                               |
| Delete Folder   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.387 |                               |
| Favorite List   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.260 |                               |
| InsertFolder    |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.747 |                               |
| OAuth           |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.152 |                               |
| Update Favorite |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.137 |                               |
| Update Folder   |  FAIL  |  90.00% |  0.621 | The operation lasted too long |
+-----------------+--------+---------+--------+-------------------------------+
```